# Mule:Database update failing although query works in Oracle

Tags: database, oracle, mule

Maybe it is a case of me looking at this for too long. But I have this Oracle update query I am trying to run, I have verified the query works with hardcoded values on SQL Developer, howver when I run it from my flow Mule it fails.can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong?

Here is the query:

```
<db:update config-ref="DBConf" doc:name="abcd">
    <db:dynamic-query><![CDATA[UPDATE myTable 
                                SET TYPE= 'Entry',
                                 ENTERED_DATE=SYSDATE,
                                 ENTRY_BY= 2345,
                                 ENTRY_DATE=TO_DATE('#[flowVars.entryDate]','YYYY-MM-DD')
                                 WHERE ID = 'abcd1234']]>
    </db:dynamic-query>
</db:update>
```

the flowVars.entryDate value is '2017-05-10'

This throws the following Error:

> Message : ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0
>   (java.sql.SQLDataException). Message payload is of type: Integer

Now the same query works like I said in SQL Developer but not in Mule, Can anybody provide any input

Comment: Hi ,   i guess  variable #[flowVars.entryDate] going as its not as date  value. Hard code date  & test  TO_DATE('2017-05-10','YYYY-MM-DD')  like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the same problem answer in the following link:
[Oracle: year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27597788/oracle-year-must-be-between-4713-and-9999-and-not-be-0)

1. Try this once. TO_DATE('2012-05-12','yyyy-mm-dd').
2. Delete the quotes for the #[flowvar.entrydate]